# jQuery call remotely web service

Tags: jquery, ajax

This code doesn't work when I host Data.ashx (this app locally). If I use url locally Data.ashx, it works correctly.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url: "http://aspspider.ws/ghadyAlhamad/Data.ashx",
    data: "{ 'MethodName': 'GetData' }", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data){
        $('#display').html("<h1> Hi, " + data.FirstName + " " + data.LastName + " your Blog Address is http://" + data.Blog + "</h1>");
    },
    error: function (err, e, m) {
        alert("error= " + e);
    }
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting ... 404?

Comment: Is the DNS working, i.e. resolving properly? Agreed with above - what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding headers either in ashx file as follows:

```
    context.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-cache");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-File-Name,X-File-Type,X-File-Size");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

or to web.config:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the app is hosted locally and you are making an http request to http://aspspider.ws then you'll face same origin policy restriction (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Try using relative url, like `url: "ghadyAlhamad/Data.ashx",` instead of `url: "http://aspspider.ws/ghadyAlhamad/Data.ashx",`

Comment: Actually I'm developing mobile app.. that means the mobile app will be locally.. and web service remotely.. I'm trying to get data remotely from javascript.
I need any help in jquery or devExpress datasource (devExtreme)..
please help me.. thanx alot